# How can I use a pandas filter and unique for the test of an if loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large DataFrame that I want to inspect a filter of one column for the presence of a unique value in a different column.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'Site Name' : ['NYC','NYC','NYC','ATL'], 'Product Family' : [5,2,3,2]})
name = 'NYC'

if 5 in df[(df['Site Name'] == name & df['Product Family'].unique)]:
    print('All good')
else:
    print('nope')
```

I get an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'method'.

I want to filter df['Site Name'] for one value ('NYC') and then check all of the rows for the presence of a value (5) in a different column df['Product Family']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need add `any`

```
if any(df['Site Name'].isin([name])&df['Product Family'].isin([5])):
    print('All good')
else:
    print('nope')

All good
```